# format for lossless video files for youtube

Tags: export, video

blender 2.79 changed up the video export options a bit and im tired of guess and checking for video formats that are lossless and play audio while not being too huge to upload to youtube. i already have the png sequence rendered, and im guessing ffmpeg is the way to go since the avi files come out huge. from ffmpeg though i still need to specify the container and the codec as well as the audio codec. whats the best way to go from there?

Comment: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en may help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about video codecs and encoding

Comment: Any video format you can upload to YouTube will **not** be “lossless”. You will have to choose a video codec, such as Theora, VP9, H.264, H.265 etc. If you want to maximize the quality, try doing 2-pass encoding.